# How to query a Facebook Oauth2 from server side

Tags: spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I've integrated Spring Security OAuth in my JAVA backend so that my mobile Android application (using the Facebook Login SDK) can benefit from Facebook Login. In the current flow, the APP uses Facebook Login SDK to fetch an access token from Android, and then passes to the JAVA/Spring backend. Then, another OAuth access token (specific to our backend) is issued  and sent back to the application.

I wish I could automate the testing, in other words being able to generate fresh Facebook access tokens. And then test the whole stuff into the access to resources on my backend. My entry point is a Facebook access token.

I've failed in generated on-the-fly access tokens, then looked into never expiring tokens, I could hard-wire in my tests.

However, I've failed in generating never-expiring tokens : at best, changing a short-lived token to a long-lived token returns a token valid for 2 months only.

I've also tried https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.xxxx.com&granted_scopes=email,public_profile , but this only works when my cookies are available (only works from my web browser).

Also tried getting a device code, but I was stuck at the point where I had to "simulate" the user submitting the code into the web form.

Is there a known way to automate the testing ?

Comment: How long do you plan your “testing” phase to go on then, if an extended user access token with two month validity is not enough …?

Comment: My plan is to have Jenkins test it, after each single commit in Git. And I wish I don't need to change it every 2 months.

Comment: You cannot get a never expiring token anymore. You will need to make do with the maximum 2 month expiry date.

Comment: @The1Fitz, would you like to provide your comment as an answer ? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @The1Fitz explained, "you cannot get a never expiring token anymore. You will need to make do with the maximum 2 month expiry date."